# VSCode cannot detect CMake directives in .h.in files

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, cmake, header-files

I'm following the tutorial on [CMake here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html). I have installed CMake Tools extension by Microsoft. Is there another extension to install for the IDE to recognize CMake directives?

[image: Code snippet]

Comment: I'm not sure why it's done like this. I'm following the steps in the official tutorial on cmake's website.

Comment: I have the same issue; did you get this resolved? Thanks!